# Material UI Slider component, update state on mouse release, while sliding in real time

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to find a way how to update the new state only on mouse release for a Material UI slider. While maintaining the ability to slide over the track and see the change in real-time.

Material UI provides 2 events: `onChange` and `onChangeCommitted`. The second provides the end result that I need, but the sliding trough the track is not visible in real-time, only at mouse release you see at what value you stopped.
Here is my component:

```
export default function RangeSlider() {
  const classes = useStyles();
  const [range, setRange] = React.useState([0, 37]);

  const handleRange = (event, newValue) => {
    setRange(newValue);
  };

  return (
    <div className={classes.root}>
      <Typography id="range-slider" gutterBottom>
        Temperature range (onChangeCommitted event)
      </Typography>
      <Slider
        value={range}
        min={0}
        max={50}
        onChangeCommitted={handleRange}
        valueLabelDisplay="auto"
        getAriaValueText={valuetext}
      />
    </div>
  );
}
```

I want to find a way to have the ability to slide in real-time, and the state to be updated on mouse release. Is there an easy way to do this?

Please also check out this [Sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-nuu3w?file=/demo.js), where I show you the 2 examples:

1. First is the sliding experience I need
2. Second is the way to update state

Comment: I don't understand, the first one works fine. What are you asking? Are you trying to fire a callback from a parent component when `onChangeCommitted` occurs? It's not clear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have to combine your examples:

```
   <Slider
    value={value}
    min={0}
    max={50}
    onChange={handleChange}
    onChangeCommitted={handleRange}
    valueLabelDisplay="auto"
    getAriaValueText={valuetext}
  />
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not just make a second state for committed change?

See [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/material-demo-forked-6cse7)

Edit: Code below.

Add state for range commit:

`const [value2, setValue2] = React.useState([0, 37]);`

On range commit handler (note: I am setting to the current state, unrelated to the mouse event this function gives me):

`const setVal2 = () => setValue2(value);`

Add range commit handler prop in addition to `onChange`:

```
   onChange={handleChange}
   onChangeCommitted={setVal2}
```

Display commited state:

```
    <Typography id="range-slider" gutterBottom>
        Temperature range (onChange event) - {value2[0]}:{value2[1]}
    </Typography>
```

Comment: I provided a link to an updated sandbox. Having written the original, the OP should spot my changes fairly easily.

Comment: @AbrahamLabkovsky, It's helpful to add your code because then it will be searchable on Stack Overflow and it won't suffer link rot.

Comment: Ok, fair enough. Added

Comment: @AbrahamLabkovsky I don't see how this solves my problem. I can still see in the console the state is updating a bunch of times when I just want to update once, on mouse release.

Comment: Ah. That wasn't clear. I thought you wanted to fire an event capturing the state on change commit in addition to the regular sliding behavior. What is your issue here? Are you trying to optimize something? Regardless of whether you are tracking it, that component must use state if something is moving, no?

Answer (score -1):

Use onUpdate!

onChange() triggers mouse release
onUpdate() triggers every change even when dragging...